# C++ class returns itself

Tags: c++, pointers, methods

I need to create a class that provides methods for 2d array manipulation. This is not a problem for me, but I have difficulty with creating a method, that returns own object.

```
Tab t(7,7,0.1);//this creates class with 7x7 array filed with 0.1 - it works perfectly
t.print(); //prints array 0 - this also works
t.set(6,6,7.5f).set(6,5,8.6f); //should set 7.5 on pos[6][6] and 8.6 on pos [6][5]
t.print();
```

I dont know what should this method "set" return. I dont know the syntax of c++ so well, because I am used to java. I see that it should return pointer to this, or content of pointer this (&this), or maby constant pointer? I have no idea.

And I dont want to use c++11.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Return `*this` as a reference?

Comment: It shouldn't return a pointer at all. You can't use `.` on pointers.

Comment: It's really unclear to me why people have downvoted this question. Really!

Comment: @MikeDinescu Well, incomplete example code (no MCVE), not showing any research and very probably a dupe, are these enough reasons for you?

Comment: Reopened. The "duplicate" was about a syntax error, not about what the return type should be to support chaining.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Definitely not! The question was quite clear to me. Yea, it could have been improved but I definitely don't think it was reason to downvote. And since when do we down vote for dupes? The OP is obviously a beginner and as a community we should aim to educate. A drive by down vote doesn't do that. It alienates people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Tab& Tab::set(int, int, double) {
    // whatever
    return *this;
}
```

The return type here is `Tab&` so that the subsequent call will apply to a `Tab` object. Returning `*this` returns a reference to the current object, so the second `set` call will change the same object as the first `set` call.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Foo {
public:
    int x_;

    Foo() : x_(0) {}
    Foo( int x ) : x_(x) {}

    Foo operator()() { return *this; }
}

int main() {
    Foo a( 3 );
    Foo b = a();

    std::cout << b << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

*Output*

```
3
```